# Gtk containers for an interactive list of items

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gtk3

Having troubles here finding the right containers to represent a list of tasks on the screen.

Basically, I am looking for Gtk containers in order to be able to:

a) create list of tasks as in "Tasque" (this is definitely possible, since Tasque is a Gtk app).

[image: Tasque screenshot]

b) create a "delete/edit" option that appears left to the task when the mouse pointer is hovered over (akin to Basecamp). (This might not be possible, since it's done via HTML in Basecamp).

[image: Basecamp screenshot]

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: You could use a `Webkit.WebView` to display your tasks and then do it in HTML, just like Basecamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the lists of tasks I would use a `Gtk.Treeview`. As for the edit/delete links on mouseover--it would be pretty tricky to do it the way you show unless your GTK application actually generates and displays lists as HTML content. I think you are best off using the `Gtk.Treeview` and either (a) have the delete/edit icons at the top of the list in a `Gtk.Toolbar` or (b) add delete/edit link buttons to the tree view iteself.

Personally, I wouldn't touch the styling of the treeview as that is probably best left up to the user's theme, but, if you had to you can use your own `Gtk.CssProvider` to style the tree view any way you want.